# SparkR 2.0: Turn of Progress

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Is there a way to turn of the progress notification e.g.

```
   [Stage 4:=====================>     ....      (4834 + 128) / 39220]
```

I'm using Spark 2.0 (and the Spark R that comes with it) on EMR 5.0.0

Even after pressing Ctrl-C (I am using the terminal R) - this progress notification continues.

Thanks

Comment: I think that's what happens when the console detects it's run in a tty. Why do you want to turn it off?

Comment: Because the progress notification continues and makes it very difficult to enter commands at the REPL. Moreover, I have a separate job progress tracker which i use and don't have a need for this one.

Answer (score 0):

The code for this is [1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/ConsoleProgressBar.scala). It appears there is one hack to turn this off, i.e. set `spark.ui.consoleProgress.update.interval` to some very large number so that output never appears after the first appearance.